# How are numerical prefixes chosen for words?

Tags: word-choice, numbers, prefixes

There are many numerical words, such as:

> Primary, Secondary, Tertiary
>
> Pentagon, Hexagon, Heptagon
>
> Billion, Trillion, Quadrillion
>
> Unity, Duality, Trinity
>
> Methane, Ethane, Propane

How are the prefixes chosen? Why are there so many prefixes for each number? For 1, there is:

1. Prim-
2. M-
3. Un-
4. Meth-

And that's only some of them. When do you use which prefix? This has always confused me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are there so many?  Because English is partially derived from Romance languages that use both Latin and Greek root words, and Latin and Greek had a lot of [numerical prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_prefix).

> Primary, Secondary, Tertiary: These are Latin ordinal prefixes.
>
> Pentagon, Hexagon, Heptagon: These are Greek cardinal prefixes.
>
> Billion, Trillion, Quadrillion: These are Latin cardinal prefixes but
>   use the multiple prefix for 2.
>
> Unity, Duality, Trinity: Latin cardinal prefixes again.
>
> Methane, Ethane, Propane: IUPAC nomenclature.  The first four are
>   derived from existing chemical names and they then switch to Greek
>   cardinal prefixes.

As to how to choose...you just have to learn them.  You can try to learn the sequences from that wikipedia link, but it's not unusual for a series to switch system partway through, as your examples demonstrate.